# Unit quarternion as rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions

I'm pretty confused by the following statement on page 6 in the book [The Seiberg-Witten Equations and Applications to the Topology of Smooth Four-Manifolds](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7ztfpc), which is meant to expain the fact that unit sphere $S^3$ in the quarternion algebra $\mathbb{H}$ is naturally associated with the group of rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
[image]

I don't think the statemet is true at the very first place, $\alpha$ does not act trivially on $\mathbb{C}\alpha$, since by that we require for any complex number $z$, the equation
$\alpha (z \alpha) \alpha^{-1}=z \alpha$, i.e.
$$\alpha z \alpha^{-1}=z$$i.e. we need $\alpha$ commutes with any $z$. But this is not even true for $j \in S^3$ and $i \in \mathbb{C}$.

Can anyone tells me where I went wrong?

Comment: Please state a clear question. (Which statement exactly is or is not true? Do you think it is true or false?) What is $C$ in $C\alpha$? Which is the exact source?

Comment: You are correct that the action of $\alpha$ by conjugation does not act trivially on $C\alpha$ if $C \alpha = \{ \left(a + bi \right) \alpha | a, b \in \mathbb{R} \}$. There might be a definition being used for $C \alpha$ that is not what you are thinking though.

Comment: This appears to come from *The Seiberg-Witten Equations and Applications to the Topology of Smooth Four-Manifolds. (MN-44), Volume 44*, which you should have included from the outset. When things are unclear, we rely on extra context to try to help.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes thats the right resource. Sorry I did not include that since I thought the notation is prob universal here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's referring to a $1$  dimensional $\mathbb C$ subspace, I think it's referring to a 2  dimensional $\mathbb R$ subspace copy of $\mathbb C$.

Apparently "the complex plane spanned by $\alpha$" means $P_1=\mathrm{span}_\mathbb{R}(\{1, \alpha\})$ and the other plane refers to the plane perpendicular to $\alpha$ in the pure quaternions.

Indeed, conjugation on $P_1$ by $\alpha$ leaves the basis fixed, so it leaves all elements fixed.

Comment: This is a live possibility. But I'm still somewhat perplexed by the claim that $C\alpha j$ would be *its perpendicular*. For all we know we could have $\alpha=j$, in which case $\alpha j$ is an element of the span of $1$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: May be the meaning of $j$ is relative to $\alpha$? IOW, $j$ is some unit vector perpendicular to $\alpha$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It *has* to be some less-than-transparent notation.  I don't trust that notation to mean what it appears to mean for a second.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  oof, the notation appears to be completely unexplained in the original source.  It is very suggestive of the plane generated by $\alpha$ and $i\alpha$.  But it is not at all clear that $i\alpha$ is invariant under $\alpha$'s conjugation.

Comment: We seem to agree :-)

Comment: Yes I think you are right about that, so here the author's notation $\mathbb{C}\alpha j$ may has nothing to do with the basis $j$...

Comment: @Lamda8 It is a travesty of mathematical exposition :/ Hopefully only indicative of the unfortunately common need of a physicist expositor to zip past all the "boring stuff" and make it to "interesting stuff."